# I do not boot from my ssd. Is it safe to comment out /boot/efi line in file /etc/fstab?

Tags: ubuntu, fstab, ssd, bootable

I am booting from my HDD not my SSD and that is a good thing. Can I just comment out the line (line 3) containing the /boot/efi until such time I actually change my mind and want to boot from this SSD?  Did they put that there just in case? Can I make it go away until that case becomes true?

OS is ubuntu 14.04LTS. Here is my /etc/fstab

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=9b4fb887-5dd8-413c-b0b0-dd3c803cf4ab /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
UUID=69A1-BD52  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/nvme0n1 /mnt/fastssd auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/mnt/fastssd/100GiB.swap none swap sw 0 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/boot/efi` partition usually contains the instance of Grub that will be loaded *if* you are doing a UEFI boot. The other option is bios, which does not use `grub-efi`. I would make sure that you are not actually booting to EFI first before you remove that mount.

Usually you can check in the BIOS and see if the drive you are booting to is listed as an EFI drive or just a normal drive.

Also, make a note of the drive and partition number for your root fs, just in case you have to do a manual grub boot.

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter if the ESP is present for daily use. Only when you're reinstalling `grub` will you need to have that partition mounted. It's OK to leave it alone, but one does need to mount it before performing `grub2-install`.